# Product view back button

Tags: product, magento2.3, custom-button

I'm using magento 2.3, may i ask how can i made a back button on product view page.
Beacuse i tried this code but not working in the product view page.
Anyone can help? thank you!!

```
<a class="action back" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><?= __('Back') ?></a>
```

Comment: `<a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr('javascript:history.back()') ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<a class="action back" href="javascript:history.back()"><?= __('Back') ?></a>
```